# Filter datatable by List<string> of column names and return result as list of dictionary objects in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, asp.net-web-api, datatable

I have a c# solution to filter the columns from datatable based on list of string columnnames, and then return the data as list of dictionary objects. I want to know if this solution is optimal or if there is a simpler and better way.

I have a webapi that returns the user profile data based on user id. The web api will have _include querystring parameter that holds the property name(s) that we need to verify and return data for. Example:
`http://localhost/SomeApi/UserProfile/100?_include=IsDeleteAllowed,IsMigrated`.

The web api should return the data with property values.
IsDeleteAllowed = 1

```
[HttpGet, ActionName("ById"), RouteSupport(IncludeObjects = new string[] { "All Properties" })]
public override List<Dictionary<string, string>> Read(int id)
{
    try
    {
        Controller userController = new Controller(ConnString);
        DataTable dt = userController.GetUserProfileByUser(id);

        // GetIncludes() method return the list of _include columns requested by the user that
        // needs to be filtered out from the dataset that has all the user profile properties
        List<string> inc = this.Request.GetIncludes();

        // Filters the columns based on the requested user profile properties (_include)
        var data = dt.AsDataView().ToTable(true, inc.ToArray<string>());

        // Convert the data into list of dictionary object
        var results = data
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(dr => data.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                        .ToDictionary(dc => dc.ColumnName, dc => dr[dc].ToString()))
                    .ToList();

        return results;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("User Read(int id) Failed", ex);
    }
}
```

In the code `userController.GetUserProfileByUser(id)` return all the user profile properties and the values from the database by userid.

The following line of code
`var data = dt.AsDataView().ToTable(true, inc.ToArray<string>())`
filters the datatable to return only the requested columns (user profiles).

Then, `.Select(dr => dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToDictionary(dc => dc.ColumnName, dc => dr[dc])).ToList()` tries to convert the result into a list of dictionary objects to be returned to the user.

Result that I get (if, xml):

```
<ArrayOfArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
 <ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring>
  <KeyValueOfstringstring>
    <Key>IsDeleted</Key>
    <Value>1</Value>
  </KeyValueOfstringstring>
  <KeyValueOfstringstring>
    <Key>IsMigrated</Key>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </KeyValueOfstringstring>
 </ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring>
</ArrayOfArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring>
```

Comment: Is there a bug, or is your code working correctly?  If it's working correctly, are you aware of any performance issues?

Comment: @dbc, There is no bug and the code works with no errors. It is working as expected, we haven't load tested this but I wanted to know if we can refactor the code to make it simpler or not. Filtering the columns and converting the data into a list of dictionary is the way to do or if there is a better way. If there is no simpler solution, then I will go with my solution.